# Setting width and height in formattableOutput() in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, formattable

Trying to fix the height and weight of a formattable output in R shiny with scrolling in horizontal and vertical directions. However it is overflowing in both directions.

Any way to contain the formatted table in a box of width 4.

```
library( shiny ) ; library( shinydashboard ) ; library( formattable )

runApp(shinyApp(
ui=(fluidPage(
titlePanel("data frame"),

mainPanel(
  fluidRow(
    
    box( title = 'Data 2', status = 'success', collapsible = T, width = 4, solidHeader = T,
         
         column( 12, formattableOutput( 'data_2_ouput' ) )
         
    )
    
  )
)
)),
server = (function(input, output) {

output$data_2_ouput = renderFormattable({
  
  formattable( mtcars,
               
               list(`Indicator Name` = formatter( 'span', style = ~style( color = 'grey', font.weight = 'bold' ) ),
                    
                    area() ~ color_tile( "#DeF7E9", "#71CA97" ) ) )
  
})

})))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to this. Adding this style option does the job.

```
column( 12, renderReactable( 'data_1_ouput' ), style = "height:500px; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;" )
```